# Merging two tables with additional condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to combine two data frames.

First data frame you can see below

```
table1<-data.frame(type1=c("A","B","C","D"),
                   type2=c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD") ,
                   value=seq(1:4)
                    )
table1
```

[image]

And the second table you can see below

```
  table2<-data.frame(
                        type2=c("AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","FFF","GGG"), 
                        A= seq(1:6),
                        B= seq(1:6),
                        C= seq(1:6),
                        D= seq(1:6),
                        F= seq(1:6),
                        G= seq(1:6)
                                )
    table2
```

[image]

Now I want to make join Table 1 with Table 2 but in a specific way. So I want to join column type 1 (e.g A, B,C, and D) from Table 1 with the same columns from Table 2 with one condition Type 2 columns to be the same in Table 1 and Table 2.

Below you can see the expected output

[image]

So can anybody help me how to do this?

Comment: just `merge(table1, table2)` ?

Comment: @VvdL I need to have a specific selection is not simple merge tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select columns in `type2` based on the `type1` in `table1` try to pass `type1` as an array of the strings:

```
library(tidyverse)
table1 %>% left_join(table2, by='type2') %>% select(type2,c(table1$type1))
```

Output:

```
  type2 A B C D
1   AAA 1 1 1 1
2   BBB 2 2 2 2
3   CCC 3 3 3 3
4   DDD 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach:

```
table2[grepl(paste(paste(table1$type1, collapse = "|"), names(table2[1]), sep = "|"), colnames(table2))][c(1:nrow(table1)), ]
```

```
  type2 A B C D
1   AAA 1 1 1 1
2   BBB 2 2 2 2
3   CCC 3 3 3 3
4   DDD 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

inner_join(table1, table2, by = "type2") %>% 
  select(type2, intersect(str_split(.$type2, "") %>% unlist, names(table2)[-1]))

#>   type2 A B C D
#> 1   AAA 1 1 1 1
#> 2   BBB 2 2 2 2
#> 3   CCC 3 3 3 3
#> 4   DDD 4 4 4 4
```